# How to select a string from the second line of a text field mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a weird database with a text field that contains a variable amount of lines of text. What is consistent is that the data that I need is a 4 character string on the second line of each field.

an example of the text in a field is below

```
Smoke That Thunders R
44' Zambia 2016
```

What I need is this "`44'`" portion, the first 4 characters of the second line only.

I need to `select` this 4 character string as a new column. Is this possible? From what I can see, `substring(str, pos, len)` would be ideal but how do you set the starting position of the of the `substring` function on the second line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the new line `\n` as substring and `LOCATE` it first, e.g.:

```
SELECT LOCATE('\n', column_name)
FROM table;
```

This will give you the index of first occurance of `\n` (i.e. new line), you can then use it into `SUBSTRING`, e.g.:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(column_name, LOCATE('\n', column_name), 4)
FROM table;
```

Here's the documentation for [LOCATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) and [SUBSTRING](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring).

**Update**

You can try with combination of new line and carriage return (i.e. `\r\n`) if new line alone doesn't work.

Comment: I was slowly getting to this solution, LOCATE is neat.

Comment: Thank you for responding, I hadn't considered `LOCATE` for this, your answer was giving me a result of blank lines so I tried this instead and it worked! 

`SELECT SUBSTRING(column_name, LOCATE('\n', column_name), 4)
FROM table;`

Comment: @Daniel thanks for the feedback, I have updated the answer.